# Argument list too long for everything

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal

I am using OS X and I started pretty much getting 'Argument list too' long for everything, what has happened?

```
user $ node app.js
env: node: Argument list too long
user $ npm install node
env: node: Argument list too long
user $ npm
env: node: Argument list too long
user $ node
env: node: Argument list too long
```

Also

```
getconf ARG_MAX gives me 262144
ulimit -s gives me 8192
```

my echo $PATH is

```
/usr/local/heroku/bin:/Users/jo/perl5/perlbrew/bin:/Users/jo/perl5/perlbrew/perls/perl-5.16.0/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.2/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Help would be deeply appreciated.

head /usr/bin/node shows:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
'use strict';
var cli = require('../lib/cli'),
    nodemon = require('../lib/'),
    updateNotifier = require('update-notifier'),
    // checks for available update and returns an instance
    notifier = updateNotifier({ packagePath: '../package' });

if (notifier.update) {
  // notify using the built-in convenience method
```

file /usr/bin/node shows:

```
/usr/bin/node: a node script text executable
```

which node shows:

```
/usr/bin/node
```

Comment: I would try tracing what happens inside the `env` module and  when it gets to calling `node`. (not a user of node). Good luck.

Comment: Maybe try `\node` and `\npm` to override any aliases you may have set...

Comment: I still get the same error: \node traider.js
env: node: Argument list too long

Comment: Show the output of `which node`, then `head` that program (assuming it's a script). If its shebang (`#!`) line is an invocation of an `env` command, show that. If it's not an absolute path to `env`, show the output of `which env`.

Comment: @KenThomases  
userx $ which node  
/usr/bin/node    

userx $ which env
/usr/bin/env

userx $ /usr/bin/node traider.js
env: node: Argument list too long'

like this?

Comment: Yes, although it would be better to put it in your question where it can be properly formatted as code. A few more: what does `file /usr/bin/node` show? If it's a script file, what does `head /usr/bin/node` show? Finally, something has misbehaved. Nothing should be installed into `/usr/bin` other than system software from Apple. Third-party software should go in `/usr/local`, `/opt`, `/sw` or the like. If an installer misbehaved to put `node` in `/usr/bin`, it could have overwritten system executables and busted your OS. I recommend that you reinstall the OS from the recovery partition.

Comment: I put them up in the question, do you think I can delete installations of /usr/bin/node (it just looks like an alias) and /usr/bin/env and be ok?

Thank you so much for help!

Comment: I deleted it and restarted everything and it's back to normal. @KenThomases thank you sir!

Comment: You definitely should *not* delete `/usr/bin/env`. There's no reason to believe that deleting `/usr/bin/node` will fix anything. Also, you presumably want to use `node` for something, so deleting it doesn't help you do that. Also, it's not clear what else may have been changed in `/usr/bin`. What does `ls -l /usr/bin/node` show? That may help identify what installed it. It's also still not clear why running it produces the error. For what it's worth, reinstalling the OS from the recovery partition won't reset your account or delete any user data. It just restores system files.